# Distributional Limit of Convergence for a Periodic Function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

> Let $f(x)$ be integrable, periodic with period $l$, and integrate to $A$ over one period
>
> Define $f_n(x) := f(nx)$
>
> Show that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)=\frac{A}{l}$ in the sense of distributions

I've been trying to adapt a similar proof for $\sin(nx)$, but $\sin$ has properties not possessed by all periodic functions so it doesn't work.

We want to show that $\forall\epsilon>0 \ \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$ then

$$\left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)\phi(x) \ dx \ - \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{A}{l}\phi(x) \ dx\right| \ < \epsilon$$

My first instinct is to combine the integrals and bound it using tools such as the Mean Value Theorem and the Triangle Inequality, but everything I try hits a roadblock.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't even have the ""we want to show" right! What you say you want to show is obviously false, for example if $\phi=0$ and $A\ne0$. What you _should_ want to show is that if $\phi$ is a test function then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $\left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)\phi(x) \ dx \ - \ \frac{A}{l}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi\right| \ < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)= f(x)-A/l$ and $G(x) = \int_0^x g(y)dy$, integrate by parts $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(nx) \phi(x)dx$$ and use that $\frac{G(nx)}{n} = O(\frac1n)$ and $\phi'\in L^1$

Comment: What is $g(nx)$'s primitive ? What can you say about $G$ ?

Comment: sorry, I mean $\frac{1}{n}G(nx)$

Comment: Did you see that $\int_0^l g(x)dx=0$ ? What does it mean for $G$ ?

Comment: It means $G$ is periodic thus $|G(nx)/n|\le C/n$

Comment: Come on ... $g$ is integrable (ie. $\int_0^l |g(x)|dx< \infty$) so $G$ is continuous and bounded by $\int_0^l |g(x)|dx$, it is obvious it is periodic.

Comment: $g$ integrable implies $G(x)=\int_0^x g(y)dy$ is well-defined and bounded on $[0,l]$ (by $\int_0^l |g(x)|dx$) and continuous. The continuity is because of the definition of Lebesgue integral / measure. If you define $L^1$ as the completion of the continuous for the $L^1$ norm then the continuity of $G$ is immediate.

Comment: I'm tired with you, $g$ is integrable on one period, it is periodic, it is trivial it is not integrable on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: It is completely trivial that $G$ is periodic and bounded on one period thus bounded on $\Bbb{R}$. There is nothing to prove, all you need is to understand what we are talking about. Take an example, try with $f = 1$ or $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ it will be obvious why we subtract its mean value before integrating.

Comment: Okay! So $G(x)$ is $l$-periodic because

 $G(nl)=\int_{0}^{nl}g(k) \ dk = \int_{0}^{nl}f(k)-\frac{A}{l} \ dk = \int_{0}^{nl}f(k) \ dk-\int_{0}^{nl}\frac{A}{l} \ dk=nA-nA=0$ 

and $G(x)$ is bounded over one period and $g(x)$ is integrable over one period since 

$|G(l)|=|\int_{0}^{l}g(k) \ dk| \le \int_{0}^{l}|g(k)| \ dk = \int_{0}^{l}|f(k)| \ dk+\int_{0}^{l} |\frac{A}{l}| \ dk < \infty$

and since it's bounded over one period by $\int_{0}^{l}|g(k)| \ dk$, every period is bounded by $\int_{0}^{l}|g(k)| \ dk$, so it is bounded over $\mathbb{R}$ by $\int_{0}^{l}|g(k)| \ dk$

Comment: The $x-\lfloor x \rfloor$ example really helped me visualize

Comment: @reuns Also, could you elaborate your argument a little bit? I don't see the argument works. I understand you want to use $G(nx)/n\leq C/n$ to be the upper bound and then conclude, but what we need is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(nx)\phi(x)|dx$ goes to $0$, right? then we have a $\leq$ in the middle.

Comment: $g(n.) \to 0$ in the sense of distributions means that for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c$, $|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(nx)\phi(x)dx|\to 0$ which is implied by $$|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(nx)\phi(x)dx|=|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-G(nx)}{n}\phi'(x)dx|\le \frac{\|G(n.)\|_\infty}{n} \|\phi'\|_{L^1} $$ where $G(0)=0,G'=g$ and $G$ is $l$-periodic thus $\|G(n.)\|_\infty\le |G(0)|+ \|g\|_{L^1[0,l]}$ @JacobsonRadical

Comment: @reuns thank you so much! I am sorry that I mixed up the definition of convergence in the sense of distribution....

Comment: @reuns could you tell me where does the inequality $\|G(n.)\|_{\infty}\leq |G(0)|+\|g\|_{L_{1}}$ come from? What is the name of such an inequality?

Comment: Please make some efforts. The name is "the function is the integral of its derivative" (fundamental theorem of calculus)

Comment: @reuns so $\int_{0}^{\ell}g(y)dy=G(\ell)-G(0)$, so $\int_{0}^{\ell}g(y)dy+G(0)=G(n\ell),$ and thus $$|G(\ell)|\leq|G(0)|+\|g\|_{L^{1}[0,\ell]}.$$ but then how do you get you get the $\sup$ norm? we don't have any $x$ to take $\sup$. I am really sorry for these dumb questions, but I really don't see it.